# Blender Rendered Image showing solid grey color

Tags: saving

I'm using Blender for the first time. I'm learning from various sources, whenever I make something and try to save the rendered image, it shows a solid grey color when pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>.

I'm not able to save any of my works.

[image]